# WebClient reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented

Tags: java, spring, webclient

So I have the following piece of code to do a GET to a remote machine:

```
webClient.get()
            .uri(myUri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .subscribe(text -> {
                LOG.info(text);
            });
```

I get this exception, no problem, I'm expecting it, but it's really hard to find any documentation how to handle these errors:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.net.UnknownHostException
```

Answer (score 9):

To handle these exceptions you need to add the following, adapt it to your case (in my case if I get an unkownHostException I simply log a warning that the requested service is not present:

```
webClient.get()
            .uri(myUri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                if (e instanceof UnknownHostException) {
                    LOG.warn("Failed to get myStuff, desired service not present");
                } else {
                    LOG.error("Failed to get myStuff");
                }
                return Mono.just("Encountered an exception");
            })
            .subscribe(text -> {
                LOG.info(text);
            });
```

You handle the error, and send something to the next step. I really wish there was a way to stop there and not pass anything down the pipe.

Comment: You can always resume with `Mono.empty()` (instead of `Mono.just("Encountered an exception")`) and hence not pass anything down the pipe.

Comment: Returning Mono.empty() is the way to go, since it produces a Mono typed just as you need, but that completes without emitting any event, so the pipe stops there, which is what yo need in most cases like this.